# Display hidden text in a circle following the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for help to display a text "hidden" behind another text when the mouse passes over it, in a circle following the cursor. I found a solution with mix-blend-mode and CSS masks, however,  this solution lets both texts appear in the circle according to the chosen colors (see below with black and purple) and I want only the purple text to be displayed in the circle. I thought about using clips, but I can't get out of it. Do any of you have any idea how to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var timer;
    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
    var xp = 0, yp =0;
    var circle = $("#circle");

    function mouseStopped(){    
                                 
        circle.removeClass('moving');
    }
   
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
         
        circle.addClass('moving');
          mouseX = e.pageX - 160;
        mouseY = e.pageY - 160; 
       
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer=setTimeout(mouseStopped,3000);   
    });
    
    
    var loop = setInterval(function(){
       xp += ((mouseX - xp)/12);
       yp += ((mouseY - yp)/12);
       circle.css({left: xp +'px', top: yp +'px'});  // 
    }, 30);

});
```

```css
body, html {
    position: relative; 
    overflow : hidden;
    height: 100%; 
    width : 100%;  
    margin: 0;}


.pro {
    color: #000;
}

.perso {
    color: #6230e1;
}

.full-size { 
    height : 100%; 
    width : 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    top : 0; 
    left : 0;
}

.blend-darken {
    mix-blend-mode : darken;
}

.blend-screen {
    mix-blend-mode : screen;
}

.mask-bg-color {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.animated-bg {
    background-color: black; 
}
.element-mask {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.circle-follow {
    position :absolute;
    overflow : hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
    width :320px; 
    height: 320px;
    top:calc( 50% - 160px); 
    left:calc( 50% - 160px); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 160px; 
    border-radius: 160px;  
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.52, 0.01, 0.16, 1);  
    transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.52, 0.01, 0.16, 1);  
    opacity : 0; 
}

.circle-follow.moving {
    opacity : 1;
}


/* hack to detect ie11 and above - blend mode not supported */
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .letter-mask {background-color: transparent; }
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .animated-bg {opacity: 0.2;}
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .circle-follow {background-color:#ffffff; opacity: 0.2; }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="about.css">
    </head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper full-size">
    <!-- This div handle the background color and texte-->
    <div class="mask-bg-color full-size">
    <h1 class="pro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h>
    </div>
    <!-- This div  wrap all other elements with blend-mode darken apply -->
    <div class="blend-darken full-size">    
        <!-- This div handle the background element-->
        <div class="animated-bg full-size">
        <h1 class="perso">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. </h1>
        </div>
        <!-- This div wrap the masked element with blend-mode screen apply and background-color set as #ffffff = white background -->
        <div class="blend-screen element-mask full-size">
            <!-- This span display the masked element-->
            <span id="circle" class="circle-follow">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="notice">
    <h1></h1>
</div>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="circle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have u tried with z-index, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Hi Asutosh,
Thank you for your answer! I will try it right now and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work... I thougt about using clip instead of masks, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do easier like below using `clip-path`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var timer;
  function mouseStopped() {
    $(".perso").removeClass('moving');
  }
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $(".perso").addClass('moving');
    $(".perso").css({
      '--x': e.pageX,
      '--y': e.pageY
    });
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(mouseStopped, 3000);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #000;
}

.pro,
.perso {
  padding: 1em 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.perso {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #6230e1;
  background-color: black;
  clip-path: circle(0px at var(--x, 0) var(--y, 0));
  transition: clip-path 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.52, 0.01, 0.16, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.perso.moving {
  clip-path: circle(160px at var(--x, 0) var(--y, 0));
  transition: clip-path 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="pro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</1h>

    <h1 class="perso">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. </h1>
</div>
```